# Entity Framework/Linq group related data

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I understand `GroupBy` and `Include` more or less, but can I group together the records that are included?

I have this working in my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.Members).ToListAsync());
}
```

Which gives me my Organizations and their Members... but I want the members grouped in to their teams. I thought something like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Organizations.Include(
        x => x.Members.GroupBy(m => m.Team)).ToListAsync());
}
```

But that is incorrect.

I'd like the returned data to be something around (but not necessarily exactly):

```
[
    {
        "ID" : "some-guid-string"
        "Name" : "MyOrganization",
        "Members" : {
            "Team1" : [
                "MemberName" : "John",
                "MemberName" : "Jess",
                "MemberName" : "Joe",
            ],
            "Team2" : [
                "MemberName" : "Jake",
                "MemberName" : "Jeff"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Without thinking too much, i could say that your problem probably come from the fact that you are returning your Entity Organisation which have Many Members, 
I would suggest, doing a Select on Organisation which return a list of anonymous objects, then you can from that select fetch Members entities Grouped By Team casted as a Dictionnary<string, Member>

Comment: If you don't mind returning anonymous type, as @DanyEllement suggested, you could try something like this: `return View(await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.Members).Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name, Members = x.Members.GroupBy(m => m.Team) }).ToListAsync());`, otherwise, if you want to use the `Organization` type, you would need to add a new field inside to store the "new" Members structure you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to explicitly include fields which are coded in your query. But If I'm wrong, then you just need to replace `_context.Organizations` with `_context.Organizations.Include(o => o.Members).Include(o => o.Members.Select(m => m.Team))` and the reset is the same.

To get a JSON output like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "some-guid-string",
        "Name": "MyOrganization",
        "Members":
        {
            "Team1":
            [
                "John",
                "Jess",
                "Joe"
            ],
            "Team2":
            [
                "Jake",
                "Jeff"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Could be done with:

```
_context.Organizations.Select(o => new
{
    Id = o.Id,
    Name = o.Name,
    Members = 
        o.Members.GroupBy(m => m.Team)
         .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key.Name, kvp => kvp.Select(p => p.Name))
});
```